# Concatenation option? '!'

Tags: sas

I have been studying basic level SAS and here is a problem that I don't understand.

```
 data test;
      A='Ipswich, England';
      B=substr(A,1,7);
      C=B!!';'!!'England';
 run;
```

According to the problem, the value of C must be Ipswich , England.

I tried the code and there are three things that I would like to ask in particular.

1),  Why is it okay to use !!  instead of || ?  Is !! a different concatenation option?

2), The result I got was Ipswich ;England.  So, I don't know what the comma is doing there instead of the smicolon.

3), Why is there an extra space after Ipswich?  Should not B be only the 7 letters from A from letter 1? As in I s p w i c h ?

The text I am working on has some weird expressions so there is a chance that it is a typo, but I do not want to go there yet.

Thank you.

Comment: Just as an addition, you shouldn't use `||` these days. The CATT and CAT functions are a lot simpler and more efficient. I suspect you're studying off some old materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `!!` as an alias for `||`.  Old keyboards didn't have the `|` character. Also old ASCII/EBCDIC transcoders didn't always translate that character properly.

Your code is definitely using a semi-colon and not a comma. So either a typo or a transcription error is why the suggested answer has a comma.

Since you didn't tell SAS what length to use for variable `B` it had to guess. So it guessed it should use the same length as the input to the SUBSTR() function call. So both A and B are defined as 16 bytes long.  The `||` operator does not trim the trailing spaces so the semi-colon is the 17th byte of C.

```
171  data test;
172    A='Ipswich, England';
173    B=substr(A,1,7);
174    C=B!!';'!!'England';
175    put (a b c) (=$quote.);
176  run;

A="Ipswich, England" B="Ipswich" C="Ipswich         ;England"
NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST has 1 observations and 3 variables.
```

Contents:

```
Alphabetic List of Variables and Attributes

#    Variable    Type    Len

1    A           Char     16
2    B           Char     16
3    C           Char     24
```

Comment: Thank you, your explanation was very clear and concise.

Comment: Actually, there is one more question.  when I used PROC PRINT, the result of C looked like it had only one space.  Why is that?

Comment: You would need to show log to see why it would look like one space instead of 9.  Perhaps you ran slightly different code and SAS defaulted the length of B to 8 instead of 16.

Answer (score 0):

1) Back in the day not all keyboards had pipe.

2) More and one extra space.
    27   data *null*;
    28      A='Ipswich, England';
    29      B=substr(A,1,7);
    30      C=B!!';'!!'England';
    31      l1=vlength(a);
    32      l2=vlength(b);
    33      l3=vlength(c);
    34      put *all*;
    35      put 'NOTE: **' c $varying. l3 '**';
    36      run;

3) Length of B defaults to length of SUBSTR argument 1.

```
A=Ipswich, England B=Ipswich C=Ipswich         ;England l1=16 l2=16 l3=24 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
NOTE: **Ipswich         ;England**
```